# android mapview blank

Tags: android, dictionary

I am trying to use Map Api v2 for few days but didn't have any success. Here is my code:

```java
package com.example.turkceasistanim;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I ran this application I got a blank map like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7H4G.jpg

So what should I do ?

Comment: Logcat, please. And make sure to put map API key in mapview.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your api key.

First you need to have the SHA-1 fingerprint of your application certificate. If you have not released your app, it is likely that you are using the debug certificate.

Find your certificate and use the keytool to obtain the SHA-1 fingerprint. Then obtain the Map API v2 key.

Guide can be found in the following link.

[Getting the Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Comment: @HalilBilgin Make sure you have all the required elements in your Application Manifest, including the api key, the permissions, and the OpenGL feature.

Answer (score 0):

How did you obtain your map key, did you use `release` key to sign your app `keystore` and then used it to obtain `MD5` key?

If yes then you will have to sign your apk again with the same key to use it, or else you won't see the app just as in your case.

To do so export the app and sign it with the same password and keystore you used earlier.

Then copy the `apk` file on to your device and install it from there, it will work.

Or the best of all sign your app with `debug keystore` and run it directly from eclipse.

Comment: I just follow https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview part I . I created a new android key in https://code.google.com/apis/console/ .

Comment: Follow this link to generate MD5 hash http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html, then use it to generate maps api key, I had this same problem 2 years ago, I solved it and you can see the solution in my answer

Comment: I followed but , i got an error : google-play-services_lib] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!